# Table View Animations and Gestures - override didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview

I've just downloaded Table View Animation and Gestures sample and managed to implement accordition in my own application.
Part that now I need to do is to "override" didSelectRowAtIndexPath that's defined in TableViewController.m from my view controller (FlipSideViewController.m).
How can I do this?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [self setUpPlaysArray];        
    TableViewController* aTableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    aTableViewController.plays = self.igre;         

    self.tableViewController = aTableViewController;
    [aTableViewController release];       

    [self.prozor addSubview:aTableViewController.view];
    [self.prozor makeKeyAndVisible];       

    [super viewDidLoad];    
}
```

What I want to do is to call:

```
[self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

When cell row is selected (go back to mainview or close FlipSideView).
FlipSideView is based on utility application template form Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Just define a method in your ViewController

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // You can hide keyboard if yo want
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    // And call
        [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

Comment: have you checked attribute "user interaction enabled" at your viewController.xib?